# Sonarqube Javascript rule "Function names should comply with a naming convention" doesn't work with functions declared in variables

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I started using Sonarqube a few days ago, but I have a question about the Javascript rule "*Function names should comply with a naming convention*".

Some of my developers do not respect naming conventions for naming functions, most of time they define functions like this:

```
onTextfieldChange1111111: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
...
}
```

And it looks like this method doesn't fire the rule "Function names should comply with a naming convention".

Is it a specific configuration to make this work? Or is there another rule to check this?

Comment: why are they calling them such lame names ?

Comment: In fact, this is a ExtJS code generated by Sencha Architect. But some of developpers doesn't take time to attribute a real name to functions, they let the framework attribute functions name with name incremented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular Sonarqube rule uses a regular expression to check the function name. By default it uses this expression:

```
^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

The function name in your question matches this regular expression. If you want to check other things, you can alter the default regular expression yourself. (You probably have to log in as administrator to change the default setting).

I think this particular rule only works for functions defined as

```
function thisIsMyFunction()
```

and not for functions defined as variables. AFAIK there is no Sonarqube rule that checks the latter. In fact there even is a Sonarqube rule that encourages developers to define functions as variable if they are defined in a code block (see the '*Function declarations should not be made within blocks*' JavaScript rule)

I know you can [write and add your own Sonarqube rules](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules), but I have no experience with that myself.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick response. I had already change the expression (I used  ^[a-zA-Z]*$) but when I run a new analysis, only functions that are declared using method :      function myfunction()      are analysed, not functions declared    onTextfieldChange1111111: function(...)

Comment: @sjeandroz I don't think there is a rule for that (see my revised answer)

Comment: extending coding rule is actually currently being improved for javascript. If you want some new rules to be added to the analyzer, you can reach devs using the user mailing list of sonarqube.